# How to Make a exe files with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, format, executable

I want to make a "Setup Maker" App with Delphi.

How can I create a exe files?

for example : Delphi Itself Compiler.

Comment: Nothing would forbid you to write a compiler with Delphi, but that's a complex task which requires deep knowledege of the processor instructions set, executable and system architecture. Alexander answer is the right one - but Windows today uses a system setup engine (Windows Installer) which in turn is driven by a setup database for a given application (the .msi file).

Answer (score 10):

if you mean installer program why don't you use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

May be you know; it is a free installer program.

Comment: I second Inno Setup. It also allows you to customise the install process using Pascal code.

Comment: Why would you make anything at all? The chance someone else have made it already is significant...

Answer (score 8):

I think that you're asking the wrong thing, since installer applications ("setup makers") don't produce/compile new executables. They have 1 already compiled exe file. They just add additional resources/archives/files to it - that's all.

Comment: It's the same for self extracting archives. It's just a premade exe 'put in front' of the zip file it self. The exe knows how to 'de-attach' the zipfile and extract the content.

Answer (score 4):

When I read "How to Make a exe files with Delphi?"... I was tempted to answer "press F9"